# Why this code isn't working? (CS50P Problem set 1 - math interpreter)

Tags: python, cs50

```
exp = input("Expression: ").split(" ")

x,y,z = exp

n1 = float(x)
n2 = float(z)

if y == "+":
    print(n1+n2)
elif y == "-":
    print(n1-n2)
elif y == "*":
    print(n1*n2)
elif y == "/":
    print(n1/n2)

print(round(exp, 1))
```

when I check the code by - check50 cs50/problems/2022/python/interpreter
I get this error:

```
:( input of "1 + 1" yields output of 2.0
    expected "2.0", not "2.0\nTraceback..."
```

Also:

```
type list doesn't define __round__ method
```

Comment: it is complaining about the error ... your exp looks like `["1","+","1"]` what are you expecting `round(["1","+","1"],1)` to provide as output?

Comment: Joran is correct. Drop the last line so as to prevent the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you cannot use a list in a round function

```
exp = input("Expression: ").split(" ")
x,y,z = exp

n1 = float(x)
n2 = float(z)


if y == "+":
   result = n1+n2
elif y == "-":
   result = n1-n2
elif y == "*":
   result = n1*n2
elif y == "/":
   result = n1/n2

print(result)
print(round(result))
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work because `exp` is a list and you are trying to use it with the `round` function, but lists do not support to be "rounded".

Answer (score 0):

```
 calculator = input("Expresion: ").split(" ")
 x, y, z = calculator

 a = float(x)
 b = float(z)
 if y == "+":
     print(f"{a + b:.1f}")
 elif y == "-":
     print(f"{a - b:.1f}")
 elif y == "*":
     print(f"{a * b:.1f}")
 else :
     print(f"{a / b:.1f}")
```

Comment: Thank you for your post, that guided me better, I just improved the format and passed all the tests. cheers!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).